# Subscribe to a buffer event in a lua plugin

Tags: neovim, plugin-development

I want to write a plugin that will watch a buffer for changes and execute different functions depending on the change.

I know I can use `nvim_buf_attach()` to subscribe to buffer events, but they are sent to "the current channel". For a moment I thought perhaps calling `vim.api.nvim_buf_attach(current_buffer, true, {})` might work in my plugin – maybe it would auto set some channel context but the call fails `attempt to call field 'nvim_buf_attach' (a nil value)` – it seems that the event api isn't exposed to the built in lua client?

The docs describe how to [create a channel](https://neovim.io/doc/user/channel.html#channel) but none of them seem appropriate for a plugin, they're all for IPC.

I would like the plugin functions to run async, so I'm not against spawning a "event consumer" process that runs alongside the static plugin bits. I'm just not sure how to do that with neovims compiled-in lua client, i.e. without making some OS installed lua package an external dependency of the plugin.

Comment: This is currently an awkward limitation. We are working on exposing RPC events to VimL/Lua.

Comment: Looking forward to it!